# Filemaker Script Trigger to Set Window Title in 17.0.7.700 not working with new layouts

Tags: script, filemaker

I've recently added some new layouts to a Filemaker solution and the window title is not updating when I switch to those windows. It still works fine on previous layouts.

Script is: 
Select Window [ Current Window ]
Set Window Title  [  Current Window ; New Title: Get ( FileName ) & " | " & Get ( LayoutName ) ]

I have previously (as in a few months ago) added new windows and the Script Trigger is there. I can see in Layout Mode that the trigger is missing on the newest layouts. How do I apply it to the new layouts?

Is this an issue with this version of Filemaker? Using Filemaker Advanced 17.0.7.700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup of layout script triggers is done in layout mode under layout setup. The trigger you want is OnLayoutEnter.
Attach your script to this trigger on the new layouts and it should work.
See more info here:
https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/17/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/script-triggers.html